# No greeter after uninstalling Evolution

Tags: boot, gnome, evolution, gdm

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS. Yesterday I uninstalled evolution and its components using the command `sudo apt-get remove evolution*` which freed something around 40 MB data.

After this I tried to restart Gnome shell using `Alt+F2` and `restart` command, which did nothing. I restarted my PC and now it only shows the loading Gnome icon with three dots; the login screen doesn't come up. Uninstalling evolution seems to have created a problem. I can access the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Is there any way I can restore the system?

I don't know steps to get gnome desktop manager back and working. I don't want to loose any of my data or settings. I tried `sudo service gdm start` which gives

```
start: Unknown instance.
```

I reinstalled evolution using `sudo apt-get install evolution` still nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

I reinstalled gdm

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

and then did `startx` which took me back into Gnome desktop.

Comment: solved my case with Ubuntu 18-04.